# Will the valgrind work for Daemon programs

Tags: daemon, valgrind

Running valgrind on foreground programs is easy. But will valgrind work for daemon programs and give the output after it executes. And how do I do that?
Thanks

Comment: Please provide some context. What OS? What is the 'daemon'?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, valgrind will certainly work for daemon programs.

Many daemons have some sort of debug mode, for example the `-X` switch to apache, which will cause them not to fork or go into the background, and in that case the easiest way to valgrind them may be by using that mode so that they stay attached to the terminal.

In other cases you will still be able to use valgrind, but you will probably want to use `--log-file` or one of the other logging options to send the output to a suitable location, and you may also need `--trace-children` to cause valgrind to follow child processes when the daemon forks.

Output, such as memory leak reports, which is only produced when the program ends, should appear as normal when the daemon is shutdown.

Comment: As a little addition to the solution - for me that only works, when given as `--trace-children=yes` - as a help for the quick readers.